# Skateboard momentum style problem with changing speeds of impact

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum

**Question:** Water from a hose is spraying at a skateboard (3 kg), pushing the skateboard forward.
The water comes out of the hose at a rate of 100 grams per second, with a speed of
4 m/s. Assume the water sticks to the skateboard and very slowly runs off (so ignore
any change of mass of the skateboard due to collecting water).
What is the change of momentum per unit time of the skateboard due to the water
when the skateboard is moving at 1 m/s? What is the acceleration of the skateboard
at this instant?

I have been trying to figure this out for a while. First we are given $\frac{dm}{dt}=0.1$ kg/s. Now I understand that the gain in momentum of the skateboard is equal to the loss of momentum of the water:

$$\Delta P_{skateboard} = -\Delta P_{water}$$

I am also assuming that the impact velocity is dependent on how fast the skateboard is being pushed:

$$v_{impact} = v_{water} - v_{skateboard}$$

Hence we get:

$$\frac{dP}{dt}_{v_s = 1} = -\frac{dm}{dt}v_{impact} = -\frac{dm}{dt}(v_{water} - v_s) = 0.1(4-1) = 0.3 \frac{kg \ m}{s^2}$$

Hence would dividing by the mass of the skateboard give acceleration?

apperently the change in momentum is $0.075 \frac{kg \ m}{s^2}$ I can not seem to resolve this...